# Polymer - start index for dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am displaying two arrays - one after another as unordered list (`ul`) using Polymer's `dom-repeat`:

```
<ul>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{array1}}" index-as="position_id">
    <li on-tap="select1" class$="{{_selectedStyle(selectedId, position_id)}}">
      {{item.fileName}}
    </li>
  </template>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{array2}}" index-as="position_id">
    <li on-tap="select2" class$="{{_selectedStyle(selectedId, position_id}}">
      {{item.fileName}}
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
...
_selectedStyle: function (selectedPosId, posId) {
  if (selectedPosId && posId){
    return (selectedPosId === posId) ? "selected" : "";
  }
}
```

I want to apply class on the selected item, but obviously it doesn't work properly because for both dom-repeat templates `selectedId` and `position_id` are the same (both starts from 0). Ideally would be to have offset on the second dom-repeat template, but it seems this feature is not supported. What would be the best workaround in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass also the offset (length of `array1`) and add them in `_selectedStyle()` (see comments below):

```
<li on-tap="select2" class$="{{_selectedStyle(selectedId, position_id, array1.length}}">
  {{item.fileName}}
</li>
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think expressions not supported in function parameter. I tried with array length and with just number - in this case function `_selectedStyle` is not called at all.

Comment: Sorry, that might be. I haven't used Polymer since a while. You would need to create a function where you can pass both values and get the result. Maybe you can change `_selectedStyle(...)` to accept 3 parameters and add the 2nd and 3rd parameter.

Comment: Yes, I did like this. I added 3rd parameter which is offset. `_selectedStyle` function now is like this: `return (selectedPosId === posId + (offset || 0)) ? "selected" : "";` Anyway thanks!